# group action on another group preserves the latter's group operation

Tags: group-theory

In the proof that the multiplication defined on HK (H and K being groups) is associative (Dummit and Foote p. 176) I do not understand the following step (the dot operation is the action of H on K, a, b and c are elements of H and x, y and z are elements of K):
(a x.b x.(y.c), xyz) = (a x.(b y.c), xyz)

Is it true in general that when a group H acts on a group K, the action (dot operation) preserves the group operation, i.e. h.(kl) = h.k h.l? Why so?

Comment: How do you _define_ "group H acts on a group K"?

Comment: This is not just a group acting on another group. It acts via automorphisms (as stated on the same page).

Comment: When you ask a question, you should provide all the necessary context; what is the action of $H$ on $K$? How is the multiplication on $HK$ defined? Also, you should use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: thank you, I can now see that this works only for conjugation!

Answer (score 0):

One general defining principle of group actions is that for any action of a group $G$ on a mathematical object $X$, the action preserves all of the mathematical structure on $X$. (This is formalized using category theory, but I won't go there with this answer... well, I did just go there a tiny bit...)

So, for example, suppose that $X$ is itself a group, so it has a binary group operation and a unary inversion operation. Then an action of $G$ on $X$ preserves both of those operations.

There are many, many other examples of this principle. Another is the concept of a linear action, also known as a "linear representation", meaning an action of a group $G$ on a vector space $V$. The vector space has a binary addition operation, and it has a scalar multiplication operation where the scalars are chosen from some field such as the real numbers, and the action of $G$ on $V$ is required to preserve both of those operations.

Comment: But we often let a group act on itself via translation, which would not fit this. So unless specified, I would not expect the group action to preserve further structure always.

Comment: In that case, $X$ is just $G$ as a set, i.e. one simply "forgets" the group structure and remembers only the set structure.

Comment: While I agree that this is what we "do", it is not really what we say when we do it (since we would often phrase it as "$G$ acts on itself"). So while an action really should preserve the structure, it can be hard to tell from the way we phrase things which parts of the structure we are remembering (and indeed, in the passage of DF this is from, the fact that the action is via automorphisms is explicitly mentioned to make sure there is no confusion).

Comment: The point on phraseology made by @TobiasKildetoft is well taken. Nonetheless, a broader and more abstract point of view on group actions can help kindle understanding in situations such as the one in this question. Here is a wikipedia link on group actions which explains the point of view in my answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action.